# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, cygwin

```
$ python3 parse_peak_user_log.py license_usage.bin  --export ~/usage.xlsx --export-type xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 455, in <module>
    parser.parse()
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 237, in parse
    return self.parse_open_file(open_file)
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 254, in parse_open_file
    if not self.parse_four_cc(open_file):
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 334, in parse_four_cc
    four_cc = self.read_str(open_file, 4, True)
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 354, in read_str
    return str_value.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The code should work as I received it from a different source and it did work for a couple of days. All of a sudden without modifying anything I got stuck with this error. I am trying to run the python script with the help of cygwin64 or Ubuntu and on both terminals I receive the same error.

I am not that familiar with python but I do understand where the issue might be. The only thing that I don't understand is that I have the following code in the script:

```
def read_str(self, open_file, length, append):
    str_value = open_file.read(length)
    if append:
        self.log_data += str_value
    return str_value.decode('utf-8')
```

Shouldn't that be the decoding issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't that be the decoding issue?

Only if your file were actually encoded in utf-8, which does not look to be the case. The "\xa5" byte represents "¥" if the encoding in your file is "latin1" - which is largely used over the World, including in Western installs of Windows.

If the presence of "¥" makes sense for you in this data, then certainy the file is encoded in latin1 (which is similar to "cp1252", with differences in few characters) - just replace your decode line for:

```
return str_value.decode('latin1')
```

and your code should work for this file. Otherwise, i.e. the character should be another thing, then you will have to guess the correct encoding of the file by other means (for example, if the file is in Cyrillic CP855, the same "\xa5" byte in the file represents the 'Ц' character).

In another note for the code above - the code attempts to read a file in binary mode (assumed, since the contest are being decoded), yet, there is no care taken for the case all the bytes for a character are not read. That is, one character in utf-8 encoding can have 1-4 bytes in length - and if the "str_value" reads a partial character, the decoding step will fail. (That even might be the case here, even if the file were actually in utf-8 encoding).  The proper thing to do there would be to simply open the file as text, and let the Python codec machinery deal with the decoding step.

In other words: whatever code creates `open_file` should do `open("<filename>", "rt", encoding="latin1")` ( (and if any other code treats `self.log_data` as bytes rather than text, i.e. tries to call `self.log_data.decode`, that should be changed as well (just remove the ".decode" call)

Comment: Lain-1 isn't the same as CP-1252. The latter has typographical quotes “like this”, which aren't present in Latin-1.

Comment: I receive another error in regards to this
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 454, in <module>
    parser.parse()
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 237, in parse
    return self.parse_open_file(open_file)
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 254, in parse_open_file
    if not self.parse_four_cc(open_file):
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 334, in parse_four_cc
    four_cc = self.read_str(open_file, 4, True)
  File "parse_peak_user_log.py", line 353, in read_str
    return str_value('latin1')
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: Your traceback shows you did not type in the call to the ".decode" method - the code in the answer does it. You have `str_value('latin1')`, when the correct is `str_value.decode('latin1')`. You should look at my suggestion of oppening the file as text to start with, tought.